# how to handle product names, ticket number in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

Suppose, I have questions about the product name, or ticket number or product id which are going to be unique every time. How to define intents for such questions and how to use entities to store it in a variable ?
**For example**:
For room booking intents, entities for room type could be single-bed room, double-bed room, king size bed or queen size.
Similarly, suppose for an enterprise product for bug tracking system, if I want to create entities for ticket number which could be anything (ex. TRS-6527).
Apologies, if this is very naive or unrelated questions.

Comment: Your question is fairly unclear. Can you update your question to provide examples of what you're trying to do and what isn't working?

Comment: @Prisoner : is the question clear to now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define **room_type** entity using **Create Entity** in **Entites** section of your dialogflow console.

[image: Room entity]

And train your intent by adding training phrases accordingly as below (Please Ignore the error here ):

[image: Training]

Now you can access the room_type as a string in your fulfillment as **params**

```
app.intent('get_room_type', (conv, params) => {

  const roomType = params.room_type;
// remember to use the same variable name that you defined as
// Parameter name in your intent to access in params
    });
```

Similarly you can achieve for ticket number as well.

Refer this [Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/#7) for example.

Hope that helps !

Comment: My question was not for room types. The problem is this ticket number, where you don't the possible combinations of tickets, which are unique every time. Room type is straight forward because the possible combination is already known to you.